# Plugin to host auctions on your site

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

Hello what free plugins are for hosting auctions on your site.
I saw wp-auction but i want the auction to be embedded in a page.

Comment: you'll get more answers with a correctly spelled question ;)

Answer (score 2):

*@solomongaby* Please take the time to read the documentation for a plug-in before discounting it as useful.  From the [WP Auction documentation](http://www.wpauctions.com/documentation/):

> #### How do I place an Auction in a Post/Page?
>
> 1. First, you need to add your auction.
> 2. Set the “Show auction in AJAX Popup?:” to No and enter the URL of
>    your Post or Page. Remember, your Post
>    or Page has to be published already.
> 3. You can then embed the auction in your Post or Page by using the custom
>    panel that shows all your live
>    auctions in a drop down.
> 4. Alternatively, you can add as many auctions as you like and embed them in
>    your Post or Page using the custom
>    panel.

Comment: from what i know that is available for the pro version of the plugin, and i was looking if there are any free alternatives

Comment: Have you tried using the Lite (free) version at all?  I'd recommend actually trying the plug-in before refuting it.